# What do you call the area in which they put furniture in a furniture shop?

Tags: word-request

When you go to American Furniture or IKEA to buy a couch, you move in a big area full of couches and other furniture. You call this:

- display area
- display room
- both are fine
- you use other word to describe this area

Comment: See my edit; I've added a store map.

Comment: As noted in the answers, "showroom" is the commonly used phrase. But "display area" is probably the best literal description of what it is.

Comment: According to plans of IKEA stores, IKEA refer to the principal areas of their stores as 'showroom', 'market hall', and 'self serve furniture area'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am not aware of any specific term for a "furniture shop". But "display", "display section", and "showroom" are general terms commonly used for this purpose.

You can't go wrong with **"showroom."**

> Showroom: a large shop in which people are encouraged to look at the goods that are on sale before buying them (Cambridge)

Check out this description of a furniture store: [Gabriel Ross.](https://www.gabrielross.com/)

> At our newly renovated 6000 square foot **showroom** in the Rock Bay Design District, you will find award-winning office chairs, designer sofas, chairs and coffee tables, ... high-end patio furniture, storage solutions, exquisite bedroom furnishings, ...

And this too: [Habitat by Aeon - Habitat Showroom.](https://www.aeonhabitat.com/showroom/)

> Our top-of-the-line **showroom** proudly features:
>
> - 8 completely unique and full sized kitchens ...
> - A beautifully curated line of furniture including Italian sofas and a large selection of chairs fitting of any sized space.

"Display room" isn't right, I think. Because the area where the furniture is laid out (at least in the shops I have been to) is quite spacious and includes the checkout counter. There may be a number of floors in the shop, but I doubt we call them "display rooms". I have heard people say "display halls" though.

---

Edit:

Have a look at this article by The Globe and Mail: [Downtown Ikea **showroom** opens this month.](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/national/downtown-ikea-showroom-opens-this-month/article657011/)

Here is another one that uses "showroom" a number of times : [Ikea to Launch Small Urban Format Stores in Canada](https://www.retail-insider.com/retail-insider/2019/11/ikea-canada-urban-format-concept-store-downtown-toronto)

Also see the IKEA store map below (it says "showroom"):

[image]

Comment: "Showroom" for sure. The "display" phrases are not idiomatic for me.

Comment: For what it's worth, IKEA itself refers to this area as the "Showroom".  Just look at any IKEA store map, they typically use this word to describe one whole floor of the store.  (Varies by location.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Thanks! Map added!

Comment: Actually you can find "showroom" on Cambridge online dictionary here
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/showroom

Also according to he same source, "the shop floor" is not the right word https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shop-floor

Comment: @Costa I had already provided that definition from Cambridge in my answer. It is referenced in parenthesis. And, yes, you are right about the *shop-floor*.

Comment: How would you use "display" in a sentence to refer to the showroom? It is possible? You can say "I saw it on display", but that refers more to its state than its physical location. Something can be "on display" in a shop, in a house, on the beach or anywhere else. "I saw it in the display" sounds weird.

Comment: @NotThatGuy "I saw it in the display" does sound weird, and I did not say that anywhere in my answer. I merely mentioned that it can be used for the purpose - I did not say how. Here is an example from Cambridge dictionary: *Our complete range of carpets is on display in our showroom.* The furniture you are looking for is on display in the hall right around the corner. So, yes, it refers to the state and not the physical location.

Answer (score 11):

When I’ve gone furniture shopping, they’ve called it **the floor**, as in

> We don’t have that in the back*, but you can have the one on** **the floor** if you want it.

*i.e., there’s not one boxed up in the warehouse. 
***On* refers to the furniture’s present condition; *have one off* would also work and would emphasise that you can take it off of the floor and out of the display area.

You might also hear it called a **model room**, similar to a *model home*, which is a vacant but decorated house constructed specifically to showcase a building company’s repertoire.

Comment: In the UK, the selling area is `the shop floor`.

Comment: @MikeBrockington In my experience (also UK) it depends on context. If it is ONLY sales, the "shop floor" is obviously the selling areas/showroom, but if the business also has on on-site workshop or manufacturing going on, the 'shop floor' usually refers to the workshop part. Not the sales area. And obviously "workshop floor" can double as a sales area as well (not unusual for e.g. a car maintenance place). So, unless you know the context, "shop floor" can be quite ambiguous.

Comment: @Tonny  The only time I have heard `shop floor` used for anything other than the selling area, is in factories, where it is presumably a contraction of `workshop floor`. In an up-market garage, you would have a `showroom` and a `workshop`, so no ambiguity there.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Up market garage, yeah sure. But the Mom and Pop shop outfit across the street from me only has a workshop (a big, single room, shed next to the house, that just fits 2 cars). The cash register sits on a corner of a workbench and that is their whole "sales" area. Whenever the owners mention their 'shop floor' they can mean 'the floor" (as in: needs sweeping), the 'workshop' (aka the shed), the 'business as a whole' or any combination of the above. And the same goes for dozens of businesses I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Tonny "Mom and Pop" ?? Not talking about the UK then!?

Comment: +1, when I read the title my first thought was "floor" or "shop floor". I'm also British.

Comment: @MikeBrockington "Mom" and "Pop" are both terms you can find in the UK....

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  Have to disagree with you there, I've NEVER come across either of those terms other than in US English

Comment: @MikeBrockington Then you need to travel around the country a bit more. :) "Mom" is used in parts of Yorkshire, some small areas in the South West, and in the West Midlands.

Comment: @MikeBrockington I am not aware of any branches of [American Furniture](https://www.afw.com/stores)—as mentioned in the question—in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

### The showroom floor

is the phrase that immediately came to mind to me.

Comment: One more word and you'd have all the answers here. *displayed on the showroom floor*. (in quotes, has ~60k hits). Hit #3 (the first two are about cars) : "This amazing sofa just displayed on the showroom floor!! Fabric and leather combo."